# reactjs running for loop with json data

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a hypothetical JSON file that reads like so:

```
{
  "main": [
    { 
      "dish": "steak",
      "side": [
         {"platter": "yogurt"},
         {"platter": "popcorn"}
      ]
    },
    { 
      "dish": "fish",
      "side": [
        {"platter": "salad"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am currently having problems understanding how to run a for loop on this data with ReactJS. The rest of my code is organised as follows:

```
getInitialState:function(){
  return {
           fulldata: {
             main:[
               {
                 side:[]
               }
             ]
           }
         }
},

componentDidMount:function(){
  var self = this;
  $.getJSON('https://yooarel.fakewebsite', function(resultes){
    self.setState({fulldata: resultes});
  }); 
},

rundmc:function(){
  return (<ul>
      {
        this.state.fulldata.main.map(function(m, i){
           return m.side.map(function(make, o){
             return <li key={o}>{make.platter}</li>
           }) 
        })
      }
    </ul>)
},
render:function(){
  var self = this;
  return (<div>
    <ul>
      {this.state.fulldata.main.map(function(m, i){
        <li key={i}>
          <span>{m.dish}</span>
          {self.rundmc()}
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
  </div>)
}
```

I am attempting to place a `<ul li>` block that lists out the different types of `dishes` I have. And then, for each dish under my `li` block, I am also attempting to place a `ul li` block that lists out the different `platter` under each dish. This is what I am trying to accomplish under my `rundmc()` function.

My code, as is, shows all platters under both of my `ul ul li` blocks. I am not sure how to output only the appropriate `platter` for each `dish`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating all the data in `rundmc` function as well, you have to pass the current dish as a parameter and iterate only the side array

```
rundmc:function(dish){
  return (<ul>
      {
        dish.side.map(function(make, o){
          return <li key={o}>{make.platter}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>)
},
render:function(){
  var self = this;
  return (<div>
    <ul>
      {this.state.fulldata.main.map(function(m, i){
        <li key={i}>
          <span>{m.dish}</span>
          {self.rundmc(m)}
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
  </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to not use a method for this, as it's very simple to nest the maps, also doesn't require React to create new functions for each child every time it renders. Here's an example:

```js
const json = {
 "main": [{
  "dish": "steak",
  "side": [{
   "platter": "yogurt"
  }, {
   "platter": "popcorn"
  }]
 }, {
  "dish": "fish",
  "side": [{
   "platter": "salad"
  }]
 }]
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>{json.main.map((main, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          {main.dish}
          <ul>{main.side.map(side => <li>{side.platter}</li>)}</ul>
        </li>))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not returning the value in the map function?

```
{this.state.fulldata.main.map(function(m, i){
  return (
    <li key={i}>
      <span>{m.dish}</span>
      {self.rundmc()}
    </li>
  )
})}
```

Edit: Didn't saw the `rundmc` method. As diedu showed, you are mapping again the same array instead of passing the actual value you want to map inside.